# How to position and scale a triangular model by knowing its vertices in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, triangulation

I want to position different equilateral triangular models, in a 3d space in unity. The problem is that the 3 known vertices aren't equilateral triangular, some of them aren't even isosceles so I need to wrap my model to match it's corners to the given vertices.
I would like to model those triangles different from each other that's why want to use pre-created models.

Currently I do the following calculation to position and scale the triangles onto a isosceles triangle:

1. Middle-point of the given 3 vertices
   `Vector3 middlepoint = (points[0]+points[1]+points[2])/3;`
2. Distance from Middle-point
   `pointdistance[i] = Vector3.Distance(points[i],middlepoint);`
3. The closest point is the one I will rotate the triangle to, so I know the triangles height (y-Axis), let's say the corner point is `points[0]` so `float height = Vector3.Distance(points[0],middlepoint);`
4. (I'm certain this step is wrong for a non isosceles triangle) I calculate it's width by determining the circumscribed circle radius, with the help of the remaining points
   `float width = (float)(Vector3.Distance(points[1] , points[2])*Math.Sqrt(3)/3);`
5. Apply the scale to the model
   `float scale = new Vector3(height,width,1);`
6. I calculate the normal `normalVec` of those 3 points to get the x and y orientation right, this works well so i think I don't need to change it
7. Instantiate the triangle
   `this.Triangle = (GameObject)Instantiate(standardTriangleModel,middlepoint, Quaternion.LookRotation(normalVec,points[0]));`

The result looks pretty good until the triangles are not isosceles anymore

(Blue line = middlepoint to closest point, Green lines = connection between the given vertices)
[image: Close view]

[image: Far view]

So does anyone have a clue how i could position and resize my triangular models to match those points?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359) You can't turn an equilateral triangle into a non-isoceles triangle only by modifying its scale once. You would at least need to apply a shear transformation as well. You could do this using nested transforms with different rotations and scales... Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish so answerers can provide more helpful advice?

Comment: For clarification, I want to place modular triangle models onto an icosphere (Geodesic polyhedron) and the triangles of the icosphere have different shapes.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't [change the mesh of the triangle](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/procedural-grid/) to make it the shape you need?

Comment: Can i change the mesh to a prefab or a fbx model?

Comment: @nimmand you don't have to bake the modification, its ok it you just apply it on Awake(), i would just snap it in, for most applications this will be fine (modify the shared mesh - the change will propagate)

Comment: @Nimmand Did you find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 2):

No code as I don't have unity handy at the moment. This answer is based on [how to shear using unity gameobject transforms](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1520058/view.html) by [trejkaz](https://answers.unity.com/users/1035431/trejkaz.html) on the Unity Q&A site.

Start with gameobjects that are a right triangle of height and width 1:

[image: right triangle model with local axes]

Then for Triangle ABC, Set the X scale of the right triangle gameobject (which we can call `mainObject`) to be the length of AB, and set the Y scale to be the shortest distance between C and the line that travels through AB (the height of the triangle measured from the base AB).

Consider the angle CAB = θ.

Then, put `mainObject` inside of a parent gameobject called `Outer1`. Scale `Outer1` with Y=sqrt(2)/sin(90-θ), X=sqrt(2).

Then, put Outer1 inside of a parent gameobject called `Outer2`. Rotate `Outer2` around `mainObject.forward` by (θ-90) (which should be a clockwise rotation of 90-θ).

Then, put Outer2 inside of a parent gameobject called `Outer3`. Scale `Outer3` with Y=sin((90-θ)/2), X=cos((90-θ)/2).

At this point, `mainObject` should be sheared and scaled into the correct shape. You will just need to position and rotate `Outer3` so that the (pre-shearing) right angle corner of `mainObject` is at A,`mainObject.right` points from A to B, and `mainObject.forward` points normal to the triangle.